# Syntax for IF statement in Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I would like to know if the following can be achieved:

Cell F4: `=IF(C4>=F3 && C4<M3) = TRUE`

When returned True I will conditionally format the cell with a background colour.

I am just unsure of how to write the formula.

Comment: When I put `=IF(C4>=F3 & C4<M3)` i do not get a syntax error however it is forcing it to =False, I want True...

Comment: Try `=Not(C4>=F3&C4<M3))`

Comment: `=Not(C4>=F3&C4<M3)` worked, appreciate the help, Thanks!

Comment: @pnuts no i didn't. Good catch.  This will work, but pnuts solution is better:  `=IF(C4>=F3,IF(C4<M3,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try `=AND(C4>=F3,C4<M3)`

Comment: I have chosen this approach.  Thanks!